# Visual studio 2015 & Android Native Programing

Tags: android, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I saw that VS 2015 supports native Android development.
What I was able to read on the matter suggested that they support apps that are completely natively built.
My team's app consists of a Java part and a native part, will VS be able to debug the c++ part when it is launched from Android studio/Eclipse with ADT? Or can VS run the whole thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio can build and debug complete Android applications leveraging C++ and Java. Visual Studio Android development story also allows to debug already built applications (.apk's) in VS easily.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/07/20/what-s-new-with-visual-c-cross-platform-mobile-development.aspx

"•You can now debug an existing Android APK without the need to build from Visual Studio.  This means you can use the powerful C++ debugging experience in Visual Studio without the need to migrate any source or build settings. To use this capability follow the steps below" section.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can only debug C++ using VS, also you have to build and start the app from VS because it adds some libs to the apk to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct with VS2015 RTM android developers can only debug C++ code. With [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) Visual Studio will allow Android developers to debug both C++ and Java code. In addition to this we will also be launching a preview version of Java code-editing features (navigation, intellisense) We would love to hear your feedback, once you try out our Java debugging and language service experience.

[image]

You can reach us at vcmdd-admin@microsoft.com or follow us at

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/ if you have more questions.